# File explorer needs to be restarted w/out admin priv. - HOW?

Tags: windows-explorer

In Windows 8 how do I restart explorer without admin privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The Explorer is launched via normal user rights, so users should be able to restart it, too. The new Taskmgr required admin rights, because of the ETW network/disk tracing. If you use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), you should be able to restart Explorer with user rights.